# Why is my CSV file coming out empty without informations after code runs w/no errors to web-scraping car parts cost for 3 brands?

Tags: web-scraping

I am very new to web scraping and was trying to get a web-scraping car parts cost for 3 brands ,Audi, Lamborghini, Mercedes code to work. The code works just fine, the problem is that I cannot get the CSV file to have any information on it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import files 
import requests

# create a list of urls for each brand
urls = {
    'Mercedes': 'https://www.mercedespartscenter.com/',
    'Audi': 'https://www.audizine.com/forum/forumdisplay.php/332-Audi-Parts-For-Sale/',
    'Lamborghini': 'https://www.fcpeuro.com/Lamborghini-parts/'
}

# create an empty list to store the data
data = []

# loop through each url and scrape the data
for brand, url in urls.items():
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    parts = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product-item'})
    for part in parts:
        name = part.find('h3').text
        price = part.find('span', {'class': 'price'}).text
        data.append([brand, name, price])

# create a pandas dataframe from the scraped data
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Brand', 'Name', 'Price'])

# save the dataframe as a CSV file
df.to_csv('car_parts_cost.csv', index=False)

# download the CSV file
from google.colab import files
files.download('car_parts_cost.csv')
```